# Generating Datetime sequence using Joda-Time API

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I want to generate a sequence of time in the following format (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) with time interval of 15 min. I will give start date and end date.

Used the below code to test the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
        DateTime dt1 = formatter.parseDateTime("2017-06-21 00:00:00");
        DateTime dt2 = formatter.parseDateTime("2017-06-23 00:00:00");

        DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(dt1);

        DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(dt2);
        List<Date> allDates = new ArrayList();

        while( dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2) ){
           allDates.add( dateTime1.toDate() );
           dateTime1 = dateTime1.plusMinutes(15);

           System.out.println(dateTime1);
        }
```

It generates output like below:

> 2017-01-21T00:15:00.000+05:30

Expected output is  `2017-06-21 00:00:00` , it's not picking up the right date which I wanted.

Comment: Look at your pattern. Does it look normal to you that the same `mm` pattern is used both for months and minutes?

Comment: I have changed the pattern to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" , still not getting the expected output. getting the same  output.                      2017-01-21T00:15:00.000+05:30
2017-01-21T00:30:00.000+05:30
2017-01-21T00:45:00.000+05:30

Comment: Don't do random things. Read the documentation to use the **right** pattern.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use java.time classes, which supplant the Joda-Time project. Convert input to standard format for easy parsing.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2017-06-23 00:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) 
).plus( Duration.ofMinutes( 15 ) )
```

## Details

As noted by JB Nizet, you are using incorrect codes in your formatting pattern. Apparently you are guessing at the codes rather reading the documentation – an unwise practice. These codes have been covered hundreds of times on Stack Overflow, so apparently you are posting here without bothering to first search.

### Joda-Time vs java.time

You are using the Joda-Time library. This project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

### ISO 8601 standard

Your input strings nearly comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. To fully comply, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to define any formatting pattern.

### Caveat about `LocalDateTime`

Your input lacks any indication of time zone or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So we will parse as `LocalDateTime`. Beware that a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is not a real moment, not an actual point on the timeline. Without the context of a time zone or offset, a `LocalDateTime` is unrealistic.

### Solution

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse( "2017-06-21 00:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
LocalDateTime stop = LocalDateTime.parse( "2017-06-23 00:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
```

For defensive programming, verify your start is before your stop. Something like `stop.isAfter( start )`.

On each loop, add your specified duration of 15 minutes.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes( 15 ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = start ;
List< LocalDateTime > ldts = new ArrayList<>() ;

while( ! ldt.isAfter( stop ) ) {  // "Not after" is a shorter way of saying "is earlier than or is equal to".
    ldts.add( ldt ) ;
    // Set up the next loop.
    ldt = ldt.plus( d ) ;
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [read the javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). The lowercase `mm` pattern corresponds to the **minutes**. To get the **months**, you need to use uppercase `MM`. So, your formatter will be like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

And you don't need to do this:

```
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(dt1);
```

It's redundant, because you're creating 2 identical objects. Just use the dates returned by `parseDateTime` method. Or just do:

```
DateTime dateTime1 = dt1;
```

And you've already created a `DateTimeFormatter`, so just use it to format the output as well. Instead of:

```
System.out.println(dateTime1);
```

Do this:

```
System.out.println(formatter.print(dateTime1));
```

The `print` method will return the dates in the format you want.

I'm not sure if you wanted to print the first date (`2017-06-21 00:00:00`). If you want this, just change the order of the `plusMinutes` and `System.out.println` lines.

---

## New Java Date/Time API

Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.

So, if you can migrate your Joda-Time code, or starting a new project, consider using the new API. If you're using **Java 8**, you can use the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the **package names** (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

The logic is very similar. The only difference is that I used `LocalDateTime` class, and to convert it to a `java.util.Date` I need to know in what timezone it is. I used the system's default timezone, which is probably what you want (as your original code also uses the default timezone):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-06-21 00:00:00", formatter);
LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-06-23 00:00:00", formatter);

List<Date> allDates = new ArrayList();

while (dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2)) {
    // get the date in the system default timezone and convert to java.util.Date
    allDates.add(Date.from(dateTime1.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
    dateTime1 = dateTime1.plusMinutes(15);

    System.out.println(formatter.format(dateTime1));
}
```

In Java 8 the `Date.from` method is available. In ThreeTen Backport (Java 7 and Android), you can use the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class instead:

```
allDates.add(DateTimeUtils.toDate(dateTime1.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```